# Fedora updates repository - getting older updates

Tags: fedora

Let's say that `fedora` repo has `hypotheticalpackage-1.0.0`. After some time `hypotheticalpackage-1.0.1` was merged into `updates` repo, and then after that `hypotheticalpackage-1.0.2`. I updated regularly and have version `1.0.2` installed, but I want to roll back to `1.0.1` (maybe because some other package depends on buggy behaviour of previous versions, it doesn't really matter).

Is it possible to somehow downgrade `hypotheticalpackage` to version `1.0.1` using only Fedora's repositories, or would I have to resort to using services like `rpmfind`? I assume that the rpm had not been cached. After browsing the mirrors it seems like only the latter method is available, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe. Sometimes.

We *do* remove older versions from the repositories, so that's unlikely to work for long. (It'd be too much burden on our largely-volunteer mirror network to do otherwise.) However, you can always find the builds for updates in Bodhi, our updates system — for a less theoretical example, see https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=firefox. This is better than using rpmfind or searching at random, because you'll know you're getting the actual Fedora package, not some modified trojan.

You can then *attempt* to downgrade with `yum downgrade`. However, this won't always work, because not all packages gracefully support going backwards. The `%pre` and '%post' install scripts can do all sorts of things, and in some cases there may be changes for which reversibility wasn't considered (an update to a config file, maybe), or others for which it's just plain impractical (an updated database schema). Ideally, packages *don't* do that — and *most* will work fine — but there's no promises.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I didn't consider the problems with install scripts, and I will try to work with Bohdi.